# Excel VBA Macro Grant Access All Files Grayed Out

Tags: ms-office, dropbox, sip

I have a VBA script that I wrote. It accesses a data file in a Dropbox shared folder using `Workbooks.Open FileName`. I just updated Excel and now when the script runs it's asking me to grant access, but all the files are grayed out.

Note that I am able to open the data file directly in Excel using File>Open without having to grant any permissions (it's a .xlsx file). It resides in the same Dropbox folder where the .xlsm file containing the script resides.

Please let me know what other information would be useful in troubleshooting this issue.

MacOS Mojave 10.14.4
Microsoft Excel 16.28 (19081202)
Dropbox v80.4.126

Comment: Is it asking for access to that folder? ie is the accept button active?

Comment: @SolarMike: No. There's a Grant Access button, but it's also grayed out.